# Problems with Booleans

Tags: c#, boolean

I am creating a time clock in C#. `Joshua` is set to `false` at the top, and when I click clock in, it is suppose to set `joshua` to `true` and skip the rest of the `if` statements. Instead, it tells me that I am already clocked in.

```
if (Joshua = false && button.Text == "In")
{
    Joshua = true;
    goto done;
}
if (Joshua = true && button.Text == "Out")
{
    Joshua = false;
    goto done;
}
else if (Joshua = true && button.Text == "In")
{
    SpeakNow("You are already clocked in");
    goto clear;
}
else if (Joshua = false && button.Text == "Out")
{
    SpeakNow("You are already clocked out");
    goto clear;
```

Comment: As a side note: using `goto` isn't a good idea nowadays.

Answer (score 4):

You've got:

```
Joshua = false
```

That's an assignment, not a comparison. What you actually want in your `if` test is:

```
Joshua == false
```

Comment: better yet `!Joshua`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Joshua = false
```

is assignment. You want to check for equality instead by using double equal sign such as this

```
Joshua == false
```

or you could use Equals which is eventuallly the same operation under the hood

```
Joshua.Equals(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

your are mixing up assignment operation `'='` with equals operation `'=='`

change all of the `'='` to `'=='` in your if statments

like this

```
    if (Joshua == false && button.Text == "In")
    {
           Joshua = true;
           goto done;
    }
    if (Joshua == true && button.Text == "Out")
    {
           Joshua = false;
           goto done;
    }
    else if (Joshua == true && button.Text == "In")
    {
           SpeakNow("You are already clocked in");
           goto clear;
    }
    else if (Joshua == false && button.Text == "Out")
    {
            SpeakNow("You are already clocked out");
            goto clear;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

make

```
Joshua = false
```

to

```
Joshua == false
```

in your first if condition

Answer (score 0):

A even better alternative you could use:

```
if (!Joshua && button.Text == "In")
{
       Joshua = true;
       goto done;
}
if (Joshua && button.Text == "Out")
{
       Joshua = false;
       goto done;
}
```

Hence Joshua is a Bool you can use the !(not) operator

Also, make sure you are changing the Text of the button as you expect.

```
    protected void button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
          if(button.Text.ToLower() == "in")
          {
              button.Text = "Out";
          }
          else if(button.Text.ToLower() == "out")
          {
              button.Text = "In";
          }
    }
```